# Remove a block of code present in a file inside curly braces in UNIX

Tags: unix, file-manipulation

I have a file from which I want to remove a block of code present inside { }. I tried using the command sed '/method2/,/}/d' filename.txt but the problem I have is I have other } inside the block I want to remove and my command removes only till the first occurrence of closing curly braces.

The contents of my file will look like this.

```
line of code1
line of code2

method1 {

  fjdsjfahldkj
  dsnfbdjvffd {}
}

method2 {
  fshfjkadhfjd {}
}

method3 {
  fkjvfdvfd{}
  snlvfk{}
}
```

I want "

```
method2 {
  fshfjkadhfjd { }
}
```

" to be removed from the file.

Note: The contents of method2 can change as in there may be other lines with more {} braces as well. Could someone help me with a command to remove this block of code. Your help is much appreciated.